# A fair six sided dice is rolled 12 times. What is the probability of getting exactly two 6's?

Tags: probability

Is there anyone that can show how this problem can be modeled by a binomial distribution?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Have you looked at what a binomial distribution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable, "number of sixes you get from $12$ rolls of the die".

- Each outcome is either a "success" or a "failure": either you get a $6$ or you don't.
- The probability of "success", $p = \frac16$, is constant: it does not vary from one roll to another;
- The "trials", namely each roll of the dice, are independent from one another;
- The number $n\ $of trials, $12$, is fixed/constant (i.e. it is $12$ and cannot be anything else/doesn't change);

Because these assumptions are good, we may model $X$ with the Binomial distribution:

$$X \sim B\left(12, \frac16\right).$$

That's how you model the random variable $X$ with the Binomial distribution.

The probability of getting two $6$'s is $p(X=2),\ $ which can simply be done on your calculator (assuming your calculator has this functionality).

Alternatively to using your calculator, see the formula at the top of [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function), and put $k=2.$

Comment: I got to this, but I thought the p value would be 1/6

Comment: oh ye, ur right. I wasn't concentrating